# I am trying for user can logged in with either registered username or email id or phone number along with password

Tags: java

I am new to Java environment so i need all your help to get on this issue. Select query which i wrote for taking username as registered username or phone number or email is correct or not ...

```
public class UserValidationAdapter {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserValidationAdapter.class);
    public boolean userInq(UserVO UserVOObj) throws Exception{
        logger.debug("Started---userInq ");

        boolean isValid = false;
        Connection con = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        //Statement statement1 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        //ResultSet rs1 = null;
        String userId = null;
        //int rowsUpdated;


        try{
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String SelectTableQuery = "SELECT user_id FROM user_details_table WHERE (user_name='"+UserVOObj.getUsername()+"' OR '"+UserVOObj.getPhonenumber()+"' OR '"+UserVOObj.getEmail()+"') AND password='"+UserVOObj.getPassword()+"'";
            statement = con.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(SelectTableQuery);
            while(rs.next()){
                userId = rs.getString("user_id");
            }


            if(userId != null){
                isValid = true;
                logger.info("Value of isValid.."+isValid);

            }   


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try{
                if(rs != null)
                    rs.close();
                if(statement != null)
                    statement.close();
                if(con != null)
                    con.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error("Exception in userInq method"+e);
            }


        }
        logger.debug("Ended---userInq ");
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: `is correct or not` it depends on what you would like to achive

Answer (score 1):

You must use column name **user_name** in front of all OR parameters

Please update your query as below

```
  String SelectTableQuery = "SELECT user_id FROM user_details_table WHERE (user_name='"+UserVOObj.getUsername()+"' OR user_name='"+UserVOObj.getPhonenumber()+"' OR user_name='"+UserVOObj.getEmail()+"') AND password='"+UserVOObj.getPassword()+"'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the select query now its working fine with the query, but we needs to add some more logic for checking the user input is either mobile number or email or username. I am going to post the query and that logic to verify the user input..

public class UserValidationAdapter {

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserValidationAdapter.class);
public boolean userInq(UserVO UserVOObj) throws Exception{
    logger.debug("Started---userInq ");

    boolean isValid = false;
    Connection con = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    //Statement statement1 = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    //ResultSet rs1 = null;
    String userId = null;
    //int rowsUpdated;


    try{
        con = DBConnection.getConnection();

        String SelectTableQuery = "SELECT user_id FROM user_details_table WHERE (user_name='"+UserVOObj.getUsername()+"' OR phone_number='"+UserVOObj.getPhonenumber()+"' OR email='"+UserVOObj.getEmail()+"') AND password='"+UserVOObj.getPassword()+"'";
        statement = con.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(SelectTableQuery);
        System.out.println(SelectTableQuery);
        while(rs.next()){
            userId = rs.getString("user_id");
        }


        if(userId != null){
            isValid = true;
            logger.info("Value of isValid.."+isValid);

        }   


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if(statement != null)
                statement.close();
            if(con != null)
                con.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Exception in userInq method"+e);
        }


    }
    logger.debug("Ended---userInq ");
    return isValid;
}
```

}

### - Logic:

@Path("/WebService")
public class LoginRestService implements LoginRestSvc{

```
static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginRestService.class);
//private ResponseVo userDetailsObj;
boolean validatePhoneNumber=false;



public Response userLoginInq(UserVO userDetailsObj) {
    logger.debug("Started---userLoginInq ");
    //String lastseen=null;
    UserValidationAdapter userValidationObj = new UserValidationAdapter();

    String lastlogin=null;
    ResponseVo res = new ResponseVo();
try{
    System.out.println(userDetailsObj.getUsername());
    System.out.println(userDetailsObj.getPassword());

    String username1 =userDetailsObj.getUsername();
    if(username1.matches("\\d{10}"))
        {
        userDetailsObj.setPhonenumber(userDetailsObj.getUsername());

        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        con = DBConnection.getConnection();
        String DisplayDetailsQuery = "SELECT user_name FROM user_details_table WHERE phone_number='"+userDetailsObj.getPhonenumber()+"'";

        statement = con.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(DisplayDetailsQuery);
        while(rs.next()){
            userDetailsObj.setUsername(rs.getString("user_name"));
        }

        }

        else if(username1.matches("[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"))
        {
        userDetailsObj.setEmail(userDetailsObj.getUsername());
        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        con = DBConnection.getConnection();
        String DisplayDetailsQuery = "SELECT user_name FROM user_details_table WHERE email='"+userDetailsObj.getEmail()+"'";

        statement = con.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery(DisplayDetailsQuery);
        while(rs.next()){
            userDetailsObj.setUsername(rs.getString("user_name"));
        }

        }

    else{
        userDetailsObj.setUsername(userDetailsObj.getUsername());
        }


    System.out.println();
    boolean isValid = userValidationObj.userInq(userDetailsObj);
    lastseenLogin lstlogin=new lastseenLogin();
    lastlogin = lstlogin.lastlogin(userDetailsObj);
    System.out.println("In Main class"+isValid);
    if(isValid){
        res.setStatus(UserConstants.SuccessMsg);
        res.setSuccess(true);
        res.setUsername(userDetailsObj.getUsername());
        res.setPhonenumber(userDetailsObj.getPhonenumber());
        res.setEmail(userDetailsObj.getEmail());

        logger.info("value of isValid..."+isValid);
        res.setDate(lastlogin);
    }
    else{
        res.setErrorCode(UserConstants.ErrorCode);
        res.setErrorMessage(UserConstants.ErrorMsg);
        res.setStatus(UserConstants.ErrorStatus);
        res.setSuccess(false);
        logger.info("value of isValid..."+isValid);
    }

     }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception in userLoginInq "+e);
    }
    logger.debug("Ended---userLoginInq ");
    return Response.status(200).entity(res).build();

}
```